# Can't zoom UIScrollView on iOS 6

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios6, zooming

There is my .m code.

```
#import "ScrollZoomViewController.h"

@interface ScrollZoomViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation ScrollZoomViewController

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"zooming");
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5f;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0f;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
}
```

I'm using Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.0 and AutoLayout closed.

Image can scroll but can't zoom. Is this because iOS 6?

Comment: yes, set delegate in viewDidLoad, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need set value for zoomScale property so as to start zooming.
Add following line after setting contentSize of scrollView.

```
self.scrollView.zoomScale = minimumZoomScale;
```

Comment: Does not work. I'm log something in viewForZoomingInScrollView, but nothing callback in running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this code:
`self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;`
 and add more content size, instead of image size.

Ex: you need to add like self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1770, 2346);

Hope this will solve.